# How can I build a Chrome extension using Flutter?

Tags: html, flutter, dart, google-chrome

I'm exposed to the idea of creating a Chrome extension using the Flutter framework. While I have experience with Flutter app development, I'm fairly new to the world of Chrome extensions. I've heard that it's possible to build a Chrome extension using Flutter, but I'm uncertain about the steps involved.

**What I tried**

To be honest, I'm starting from scratch in this area. I haven't attempted anything yet because I'm not sure where to begin. My Flutter knowledge is fairly solid, but I'm not sure how to adapt it for building Chrome extensions.

I also had a look at [the official documentation](https://docs.flutter.dev/platform-integration/web/building). However, I couldn't find any resources.

**Specifically, I'm Unsure About:**

How do I structure a Flutter project to function as a Chrome extension? specifically:
what modifications are needed in project files (e.g., *index.html*, *manifest.json*) to enable extension functionality?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

*Make sure you have the latest version of Flutter.*

*To add web support to an existing project created using a previous version of Flutter, run the following command from your project’s top-level directory*:

```
flutter create --platforms web .
```

## Setup

### 1. Modifying *index.html*:

Navigate to the `web/index.html` file to remove any non-supported scripts:

- Insert the following `<script>` tag inside the `<body>` tag :

```js
<script src="main.dart.js" type="application/javascript"></script>
```

**Set Extension View Dimensions**:

Define fixed dimensions for the extension view by modifying the starting `<html>` tag in *web/index.html*:

```html
<html style="height: 600px; width: 350px">
```

Your modified `index.html` should now look like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html style="height: 600px; width: 300px">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <title>chromextension</title>
</head>
<body>
<script src="main.dart.js" type="application/javascript"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

### 2. Modifying *manifest.json*:

Replace the content of `web/manifest.json` file with the appropriate extension configuration, including name, description, version, content security policy, default popup, and icon:

```json
{
    "name": "extension demo",
    "description": "demo",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "content_security_policy": {
        "extension_pages": "script-src 'self' ; object-src 'self'"
    },
    "action": {
        "default_popup": "index.html",
        "default_icon": "icons/Icon-192.png"
    },
    "manifest_version": 3
}
```

## Build the extension

Generate a Flutter web build using the HTML renderer and the `--csp` flag to disable dynamic code generation:

```
flutter build web --web-renderer html --csp
```

(Every time you change your code, you should rebuild the extension).

## Install and test the extension

- Open Chrome and type `chrome://extensions` in the URL address bar.
- Enable Developer mode.
- Click on "Load unpacked" and select the `<flutter_project_dir>/build/web` folder. (Again, select the **build**/web folder)

[image]

The extension will now be installed and accessible from the Chrome extension bar:

[image]