Could not load manifest
'content_security_policy.extension_pages': Insecure CSP value https://www.gstatic.com in directive 'script-src'.  When I was building a plugin for chrome with flutter, and using the v3 of manifest does not allow me to download the wanted datas for the flutter.
{
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "name": "A SAMPLE FLUTTER CHROME PLUGIN",
    "version": "1.0",
    "description": "",
    "permissions": [
      "activeTab",
      "tabs",
      "storage",
      "scripting",
      "*://*/*"
    ],
    "background": {
      "service_worker": "background.js",
      "type": "module"
    },
    "content_scripts": [
      {
        "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
        "js": ["content.js"]
      }
    ],
    "action": {
      "default_popup": "index.html"
    },
    "icons": {
      "192": "icons/Icon-192.png",
      "512": "icons/Icon-512.png"
    },
    "web_accessible_resources": [
      {
        "resources": ["manifest_flutter.json"],
        "matches": ["*://*.example.com/*"]
      }
    ],
    "content_security_policy": {
      "extension_pages": "script-src 'self' https://www.gstatic.com; object-src 'self'"
    },
    "externally_connectable": {
      "matches": ["*://*.example.com/*"]
    }
  }


https://stackoverflow.com/q/76883562/12349734
